# Compiling with py_compile

Tags: python, compilation

This is more of a 'toy question' than a real one, but can you compile a single line of Python code from the command line using the `py_compile` module?

My first attempt was `python -m py_compile "print 'Hello, Compile!'"` but that resulted in an `IOError` because `my_compile` thought that I was trying to compile a file named "print 'Hello, Compile!'".

Any ideas?

Note: `python -c "CODE"` runs the code, it does not produce a *.pyc file with the bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  `py_compile` and `compileall` are meant to be used on files.  You could use some tempfiles of course but that's unnecessary.

Instead: are you just trying to use `dis`?  You can read from stdin interactively (or from a pipe) by specifying `-`:

```
ben@nixbox:~$ echo "print 'hello'" | python -m dis -
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('hello')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `py_compile` module to compile things -- the CPython interpreter *always* compiles to bytecode before execution.

The real question here is, what do you want it to do with the bytecode after you've compiled it?

Here's one possible thing you might have in mind:

```
$ python -c '
def f():
  print "Hello, World"
import dis
dis.dis(f)'
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello, World')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

I don't think this is possible as a true "single line" (with no newlines embedded in the command), because of Python's syntax, but you see the idea.